# How we can assoaociate a Hub site with Hub site

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, office-365, administration, hub-site

We have the following sites hierarchy that we want to build inside our company:-

```
*Root Site*
      *Departments*
         **HR**
           HR Central
           HR Users 
           HR Managers
        **Finance**
           ...
        **IT**
           ...
```

so in our case we will have the Root as a hub and associate with it another Hub site named Departments. Then associate the departments (HR, Finance, IT) with the Departments , as so on.

But seems if we define a site as hub site, then we can not associate it with another hub site (for example in the Departments case, it can not be a Hub site for the HR,Finance & IT sites + at the same time to have the Departments linked to the Root hub site).. so how we can build the above hierarchy in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Associate a SharePoint hub site to another hub to connect search experiences](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hub-to-hub-association?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698) for the documentation on how to associate a SharePoint hub site to another hub site.

[image]